# Get "Trending Music" at Explore page using PHP HTML Parser

Tags: php, html, html-parsing, soundcloud

I tried to get the songs from the explore page from SoundCloud to get the "Trending Music". I have a PHP script whicht gets the contents from the explore page.

I'm using the "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser" (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). I modified my request and set my user-agent to the latest Firefox user-agent.

Looks like this:

```
$opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
          "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n".
          "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.soundcloud.com/explore/',false,$context);
```

But now I get the error page from SoundCloud saying: "Sorry! We can't find that page."
When I open that URL directly in the browser it works. I think some javascript is getting the actual data, can anybody help me please?

Comment: Just a reminder that if you want to release this to public in any way it'd break SoundCloud's terms of use

Comment: come on, when will there be a way to do that using your SoundCloud API? I read some posts from  1 year ago or so saying that you work on that..